# Pass a variable as a regex

Tags: java, regex

I have this code:

```
private boolean setListOfRegex() {
    try {
        listRegex = new ArrayList<Pattern>();
        tokens = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        String[] regs = regexFile.split("\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < regs.length; i++) {
            String[] info = regs[i].split(";");
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile(info[0]);
            listRegex.add(p);
            String[] a = { info[1], info[2] };
            tokens.add(a);
        }
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
```

The array `regs` is the array result of the `regexFile`, where `regexFile` is a .txt file like this one:

```
\\+|\\*|\\*\\*|\\-|\\=;OPERATOR;0
\\w+\s\\=;VARIABLE;1
\\(;OPEN_BRACKET;2
\\);CLOSE_BRACKET;3
[0-9]+;NUMBER;4
```

The function work fine, but the problem is the line:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(info[0]);
```

When I change the `info[0]` for `"\\\\("`, it works fine, but with the variable doesn't, I print the `info[0]`, and it shows the same string, so when I leave the variable show this error:

```
Unclosed group near index 3 
\\\\(
```

It seems that took the parentheses like the parentheses of some regex expression. I think it's because the `info[0]` should be `"\\\\\\\\\("`. I try with that expression, but the error remains:

```
Unclosed group near index 5 
\\\\(
```

How can save the expression `"\\\\("` in `info[0]`. The two expressions before this one:

```
\\+|\\*|\\*\\*|\\-|\\=;OPERATOR;0
\\w+\s\\=;VARIABLE;1
```

compile fine

Comment: Almost. The info file sholud contain `\(` and not `\\(`. The other one just isn't a valid regex. When you write `"\\("` in Java that is actually the string `\(`.

Comment: Yes, this is super confusing if you're new, but Java regex is the same as any other regex.  It's Java *String literal* that requires encoding.  If you're reading a file it's not a literal, it's just data, so you type the regex without the extra '\'.

Answer (score 2):

> When I change the info[0] for "\\(", it works fine, but with the
> variable doesn't

This is not correct.

**Demo:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern.compile("\\\\(");
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed group near index 3
\\(
...
```

And as expected, the behaviour remains same with a variable

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "\\\\(";
        Pattern.compile(str);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed group near index 3
\\(
...
```

### The reason for this behaviour

The string, `\\\\(` means a `\` followed by an unescaped `(` which the regex engine interprets as the start of a group. This is because `\\\\` is interpreted as a single `\` by the regex engine - one `\` to escape `\` and then `\\` to escape the escaped `\` which is like escaping `[` with `\\[`.

Thus, you need `\\` to escape `(` and therefore your string should be `\\\\\\(` where `\\\\` specifies an escaped `\` and `\\(` specifies an escaped `(`.

**Demo:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //...
        Pattern.compile("\\\\\\(");
        
        String str = "\\\\\\(";
        Pattern.compile(str);
        //....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The file content `\\(` is equivalent to the Java string literal `"\\\\("`, i.e. two (literal) backslashes followed by an opening parenthesis. To escape a meta character in a regular expression, it needs to be preceded by a single backslash. This includes the backslash character itself, which can be escaped with another preceding backslash.

If you cannot modify the file, then you have to remove the duplicated backslashes and replace them with a single backslash before compiling them as a regular expression:

```
// replace 2 literal backslash character with a single literal backslash character:
info[0] = info[0].replace("\\\\", "\\");
```